# Using a while loop to keep numbers but discard words

Tags: python, while-loop

Using while loops in Python, I have been asked to complete this task for university but I cannot seem to figure out how to do it:

> Ask for a number, and if the response is actually NOT a number (e.g. "cow", "six", "8!") then throw it out and ask for an actual number. When you do get a number, return it.

If anyone could show me how to do this that would be great!

I started out with this, although I'm not sure if it is the right starting point:

```
while () #not sure what to put in here
    number_a = input("Enter an actual number:")
    number_b = int(num_string)
return (
```

I'm not sure what to type after the `while` to make it work for numbers not words.

Comment: You must know how to do _most_ of this? How to do something repeatedly, how to ask for `input`, how to `try` to convert that to an `int`, how to `return` a value? Write the parts you do know, and point to the part you don't know, and we can help you.

Comment: The code you added is a good start.  The function `input()` returns a string.  So your variable `number_a` will be a string.  Using the `int()` function to convert it to an integer is the right way to go but it will raise an error if `number_a` is not convertible into an integer.  So you need a way to handle that error and ask the user to re-enter the number if it occurs.  For this, use the [`try` and `except` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

Comment: @Bill I clicked approve on your edit, but looking at it again, I think you wanted to keep (and reformat) the second version of the code, not the first one—it has the `while` and the `return`, and a valid comment about the missing part instead of a stray SyntaxError. (And now it won't let me re-edit until your edit is approved or rejected.)

Comment: @abarnert Fixed the edit mess for you ;)

Comment: (1) To loop forever, you can use `while True:` (No parentheses, but you d need a colon.) That means you'll need a `break` or `return` indented inside the loop, or it really will loop forever. (2) You call `int(num_string)`, that means you have to have to have a `num_string`—but the only thing you have is `number_a`. You'll need to rename something. (3) What happens if the string is `"cow"`? Try `int("cow")` in the interactive interpreter and see what happens. Do you get an exception? Then you need to use `try:` and `except (that error type):` around the `int` call.

Comment: (4) Inside that `except` block, you don't need to do anything—you're just going to return to the top of the loop. But Python won't let you put nothing there, so use `pass`, which means "do nothing".

Answer (score -1):

Try using try/except construction:

```
inp = "" 
print('Type a number') 
while 1:
    inp = input()
    try:
        int(inp)
        break
    except TypeError:
        print('Try again') 
        continue
print('Your number is', int(inp))
```

Comment: Did you just copy and paste the other answer with irrelevant minor changes? Because it does the exact same thing, and has the exact same problems.

Comment: sorry, how do I delete it?

Comment: Right underneath the answer, you should see links "share edit delete flag". Some of them may be greyed out because your rep is too low, but I think you should be able to click delete on your own answers.

Comment: I'm on my mobile and I have only edit share and flag

Answer (score -1):

```
stop = False
while (stop == False):
    x = input("Enter an actual number: ")
    try:
        print(int(x))
        stop = True
    except Exception:
        continue
```